# Can we expire product after user buys from Google In-App Purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am implementing Google In-App Purchase in my app,

Here the user will purchase will my app for xx Rs, and after purchasing it the user will be able to use the app for 2 years.

is it possible/allowed to expire the user after the user purchase the product?
Can the user purchase the same product after 2Years?

Is it possible/allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subscription instead an in-app product and automatically the user will have to pay again when it expires to renew it.

Subscriptions can be created for 1 month, 6 months or 1 year but not for 2 years.

It would be possible to renew every 2 years if you use an in-app product instead suscription and then consume the product when the time expires, but you will have to control the time yourself, surely through a server or Firebase, this would not be necessary with subscriptions.